# Как ограничить скрол изображения?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

Как ограничить скрол изображения, чтобы скрол не выходил за границы картинки (на скрине пример выхода за границы картинки)? Картинка одного размера на все размеры девайсов. И еще вопрос, каким образом можно настроить, чтобы при запуске этого экрана картинка отображалась с верхнего левого угла, а не с нижнего? Изображение размещено на скролвью через Reset to Suggested Constraints

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: В последнем скрине видно что и где находится

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скрол не выходил за границы картинки пропишите:

```
scrollView.bounces = false
```

А по дополнительному вопросу нужно смотреть как что расположили.

Comment: С первым вопросом все работает, спасибо большое! По второму добавил скрин

Comment: @ArturSkachkov ничего не понятно по скрину, можете скинуть проект? Можете все поудалять, главное только чтоб воспроизводилась Ваша проблема с ScrollView

Comment: Вот ссылочка на проект https://yadi.sk/d/nTioCAYm3HsWkj

Comment: @ArturSkachkov так оно же и так показывается с верхнего левого угла.

Comment: у меня на всех девайсах отображается от левого нижнего угла

Comment: @ArturSkachkov странно, не получается воспроизвести.  Но попробуцте в viewDidAppear прописать scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)

Comment: Не изменилось ((